# Why are my not getting dynamic values from a button using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I created a dynamic button,and used ajax to call it when clicked. when each of the button is clicked it fetches a list of items from a website, which makes it dynamic.

```
 foreach($items as $item_link){
    $i++;
    $item_name = $name[$i];
    <button type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="'.$item_link[$i].'" onclick= " getItem(this.value);">'.$item_name.'</button>
 }
```

I noticed that when each of the buttons are clicked it only return the same value,instead of dynamically returning different values of the button.
My question is: what could be the cause? Although the button is not in a form, could that also be a reason?

Comment: Creating dynamic elements with duplicate `ID`'s can cause multiple problems but I don't see where you attempt to append this button. You haven't even stored it into a variable so as your source code stands it will throw a syntax error. I suggest you format the source code in your question so it doesn't mislead anyone into thinking you are trying to execute the script as it looks in your question.

Comment: 1. convert `id="btn"` to `class="btn"`, because `id` need to be unique per element.2.What data you are fetching on button click(add that code so that we can check). 3. Add the HTML part also for more clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Initially and in `foreach()` also change button  `id` to `class`.

2.You haven't `echod` your button, so i don't think it's coming at all. So `echo` it and sorrund the button with quotes.

***Proper code:-***

```
foreach($items as $item_link){
    $i++;
    $item_name = $name[$i];
    echo '<button type="button" class="btn" name="btn" value="'.$item_link[$i].'" onclick= "getItem(this.value);">'.$item_name.'</button>';
 }
```

***Note:-***

id need to be unique per element, otherwise when you are using it in jquery you will get always first element data.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this, I would prefer this one:-

1. Add the onclick event to button and pass unique id or name to it.

   ```
   <button onclick="fun('<?=$name?>')">click me</button>
   ```
2. In method fun call the ajax request and pass the name or id to it which you recieved as a function parameter.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you are using the same ID for all the buttons and that will bring unexpected behavior to the browser. You need to change for something like this:

```
foreach($items as $item_link){ 
  $i++; 
  $item_name = $name[$i]; 
  <button type="button" id="'.$item_link[$i].'" name="btn" value="'.$item_link[$i].'" onclick= " getItem(this.value);">'.$item_name.'</button>
}
```

Or simply get rid of the ID and use a class instead